# Compare 2 excel file large data write result with Highlight cellstyle sxssf JAVA

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, apache-poi

How can I compare 2 excel sheet content large data over 40,000 rows each cell and highlight not equal cell in red color under new result file .

- Below code have I have successful able to work with comparing 2 file but when I write the result file I get error for java.lang.NullPointerException for row3edit.setRowStyle(cellStyleRed);at method compareTwoSheets line 15
- Have copied 2nd excel file[Prod_Rel.xlsx] using java code to create a result file with data which will highlight not equal data.[ is there a better way to write result file]
- Used SXSSFWorkbook to keep 100 rows in memory, exceeding rows will be flushed to disk.
- XSSF cellStyleRed as SXSSFWorkbook cannot have cellstyle color and then convert to SXSSF

**Please read the code before posting reply **

package pageobjects;

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystem;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FillPatternType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.testng.Reporter;

import property.IHomePage;
import utility.SeleniumUtils;

public class Excelcom2try extends SeleniumUtils implements IHomePage {
    public static FileOutputStream opstr = null;
    XSSFCellStyle cellStyleRed = null;
    SXSSFWorkbook sxssfWorkbook = null;
    SXSSFSheet sheet = null;
    SXSSFRow row3edit = null;
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
public void compare() {
    try {
        // Create new file for Result 
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("\\\\sd-cd6b\\Selenium\\comparisonfile\\ResultFile.xlsx"));
        workbook.write(fos);
        workbook.close();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        // get input for 2 compare excel files
        FileInputStream excellFile1 = new FileInputStream(new File("\\\\sd-cd6b\\Selenium\\comparisonfile\\UAT_Rel.xlsx"));
        FileInputStream excellFile2 = new FileInputStream(new File("\\\\sd-cd6b\\Selenium\\comparisonfile\\Prod_Rel.xlsx"));
        // Copy file 2 for result to highlight not equal cell
        FileSystem system = FileSystems.getDefault();
        Path original = system.getPath("\\\\sd-cd6b\\Selenium\\comparisonfile\\Prod_Rel.xlsx");
        Path target = system.getPath("\\\\sd-cd6b\\Selenium\\comparisonfile\\ResultFile.xlsx");

        try {
            // Throws an exception if the original file is not found.
            Files.copy(original, target, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            Reporter.log("Successfully Copy File 2 for result to highlight not equal cell");
            Add_Log.info("Successfully Copy File 2 for result to highlight not equal cell");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Reporter.log("Unable to Copy File 2 ");
            Add_Log.info("Unable to Copy File 2 ");
        }
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        FileInputStream excelledit3 = new FileInputStream(new File("\\\\sd-cd6b\\Selenium\\comparisonfile\\ResultFile.xlsx"));
        // Create Workbook for 2 compare excel files
        XSSFWorkbook workbook1 = new XSSFWorkbook(excellFile1);
        XSSFWorkbook workbook2 = new XSSFWorkbook(excellFile2);
        // Temp workbook 
        XSSFWorkbook workbook3new = new XSSFWorkbook();
        //XSSF cellStyleRed as  SXSSFWorkbook cannot have cellstyle  color
        cellStyleRed = workbook3new.createCellStyle();
        cellStyleRed.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
        cellStyleRed.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

        // Get first/desired sheet from the workbook to compare both excel sheets
        XSSFSheet sheet1 = workbook1.getSheetAt(0);
        XSSFSheet sheet2 = workbook2.getSheetAt(0);
        //XSSFWorkbook workbook3new temp convert to SXSSFWorkbook
        // keep 100 rows in memory, exceeding rows will be flushed to disk
        sxssfWorkbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(workbook3new, 100);
        sheet = sxssfWorkbook.createSheet();
        // Compare sheets
        if (compareTwoSheets(sheet1, sheet2, sheet)) {

            Reporter.log("\\n\\nThe two excel sheets are Equal");
            Add_Log.info("\\n\\nThe two excel sheets are Equal");
        } else {
            Reporter.log("\\n\\nThe two excel sheets are Not Equal");
            Add_Log.info("\\n\\nThe two excel sheets are Not Equal");

        }

        // close files
        excellFile1.close();
        excellFile2.close();
        excelledit3.close();
        opstr.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Reporter.log("Successfully Close All files");
    Add_Log.info("Successfully Close All files");
}

// Compare Two Sheets
public boolean compareTwoSheets(XSSFSheet sheet1, XSSFSheet sheet2, SXSSFSheet sheet) throws IOException {
    int firstRow1 = sheet1.getFirstRowNum();
    int lastRow1 = sheet1.getLastRowNum();
    boolean equalSheets = true;
    for (int i = firstRow1; i <= lastRow1; i++) {

        Reporter.log("\n\nComparing Row " + i);
        Add_Log.info("\n\nComparing Row " + i);
        XSSFRow row1 = sheet1.getRow(i);
        XSSFRow row2 = sheet2.getRow(i);

        row3edit = sheet.getRow(i);
        if (!compareTwoRows(row1, row2, row3edit)) {
            equalSheets = false;
            // Write if not equal
// Get error here java.lang.NullPointerException for row3edit.setRowStyle(cellStyleRed);
            //if disable test is completed Successfully without writing result file 
            row3edit.setRowStyle(cellStyleRed);
            Reporter.log("Row " + i + " - Not Equal");
            Add_Log.info("Row " + i + " - Not Equal");
            // break;
        } else {
            Reporter.log("Row " + i + " - Equal");
            Add_Log.info("Row " + i + " - Equal");
        }
    }
    // Write if not equal 
    opstr = new FileOutputStream("\\\\sd-cd6b\\Selenium\\comparisonfile\\ResultFile.xlsx");
    sxssfWorkbook.write(opstr);

    opstr.close();

    return equalSheets;
}

// Compare Two Rows
public boolean compareTwoRows(XSSFRow row1, XSSFRow row2, SXSSFRow row3edit) throws IOException {
    if ((row1 == null) && (row2 == null)) {
        return true;
    } else if ((row1 == null) || (row2 == null)) {
        return false;
    }

    int firstCell1 = row1.getFirstCellNum();
    int lastCell1 = row1.getLastCellNum();
    boolean equalRows = true;

    // Compare all cells in a row

    for (int i = firstCell1; i <= lastCell1; i++) {
        XSSFCell cell1 = row1.getCell(i);
        XSSFCell cell2 = row2.getCell(i);
        if (!compareTwoCells(cell1, cell2)) {
            equalRows = false;
            Reporter.log("       Cell " + i + " - NOt Equal " + cell1 + "  ===  " + cell2);
            Add_Log.info("       Cell " + i + " - NOt Equal " + cell1 + "  ===  " + cell2);
            break;
        } else {
            Reporter.log("       Cell " + i + " - Equal " + cell1 + "  ===  " + cell2);
            Add_Log.info("       Cell " + i + " - Equal " + cell1 + "  ===  " + cell2);
        }
    }
    return equalRows;
}

// Compare Two Cells
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static boolean compareTwoCells(XSSFCell cell1, XSSFCell cell2) {
    if ((cell1 == null) && (cell2 == null)) {
        return true;
    } else if ((cell1 == null) || (cell2 == null)) {
        return false;
    }

    boolean equalCells = false;
    int type1 = cell1.getCellType();
    int type2 = cell2.getCellType();
    if (type2 == type1) {
        if (cell1.getCellStyle().equals(cell2.getCellStyle())) {
            // Compare cells based on its type
            switch (cell1.getCellType()) {
            case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                if (cell1.getCellFormula().equals(cell2.getCellFormula())) {
                    equalCells = true;
                } else {
                }
                break;

            case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                if (cell1.getNumericCellValue() == cell2.getNumericCellValue()) {
                    equalCells = true;
                } else {
                }
                break;
            case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                if (cell1.getStringCellValue().equals(cell2.getStringCellValue())) {
                    equalCells = true;
                } else {
                }
                break;
            case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                if (cell2.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                    equalCells = true;

                } else {
                }
                break;
            case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                if (cell1.getBooleanCellValue() == cell2.getBooleanCellValue()) {
                    equalCells = true;
                } else {
                }
                break;
            case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                if (cell1.getErrorCellValue() == cell2.getErrorCellValue()) {
                    equalCells = true;
                } else {
                }
                break;
            default:
                if (cell1.getStringCellValue().equals(cell2.getStringCellValue())) {
                    equalCells = true;
                } else {
                }
                break;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return equalCells;
}
```

}

Comment: I removed the Selenium tag since this question has nothing to do with Selenium. You said you get an NPE on calling `setRowStyle()` but you didn't include the method or indicate on which line of that method is causing the issue. Rather than trying to get your entire project working, instead create a side project where you just color a chosen cell as red... can you get that to work? That's why it's expected that you provide a [mcve] because you've provided WAY more code than is necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: provide all code because if there is a different way to write result file would help others to answer the question by reviewing the full code

Comment: As I already mentioned, SO guidelines are to provide an MCVE not the full code. Also, you haven't provided the "full code" because the one method that's throwing the NPE has not been provided.

Comment: @JeffC I have provide all method please check public boolean compareTwoSheets method line 15

Comment: @OlafKock No I get error for row3edit.setRowStyle(cellStyleRed);

Comment: So apparently row3edit is null...

Comment: @OlafKock can you please explain how row3edit is null;

Comment: You get `row3edit` via `row3edit = sheet.getRow(i);` where `sheet` was got via `sxssfWorkbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(workbook3new, 100); sheet = sxssfWorkbook.createSheet();`  where `XSSFWorkbook workbook3new = new XSSFWorkbook();`. So `sheet` is a new created `SXSSFSheet` in a new created `SXSSFWorkbook` from a new created empty `XSSFWorkbook`. It has no rows so `sheet.getRow` always returns `null`. Rows need to be created using `sheet.createRow`. So `row3edit = sheet.getRow(i); if (row3edit == null) row3edit = sheet.createRow(i);`.